# How can I access multiple animations in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, arkit

[Image of the file hierarchy in xcode of my animation file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtisr.png)

**Issue:**

xcode is recognizing multiple animations for a single Collada (.dae) file. But I can't find any documentation on how to access these animations directly. I tried using the fox game example, but it only loads one of the animations.

**Here's my code:**

```
let modelNode = self.addModel_DAE_return(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, scaleFactor: 0.0005, fileName: "models.scnassets/export_014/export_014_model.dae")

// add the animation to the model

let modelAnim = self.loadAnim_DAE(fileName: "models.scnassets/export_014/export_014_anim.dae")
                modelNode.addAnimationPlayer(modelAnim, forKey: "headMove")

modelAnim.play()

// add the model to the scene
node.addChildNode(modelNode)
```

**How can I access and load in the other animations?**

**Context:**

I'm making an AR app. I'm using the Apple Image Recognition example as a base.

Here's a link to it: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/recognizing_images_in_an_ar_experience

I animated a skeleton in Maya and exported the animation to a COLLADA (.DAE) file using the OpenCollada extension for Maya.

I exported separate files for the model and the animation, because if I export them as a single file, none of my animations export and xcode crashes every time I try to access the file to check if it registers any animations.

I want to access the "Entities" of my animation file so I can just loop over, load and attach the animations, but I can't

also I have looked into GameKit kind of but, is there not a way to do this with SceneKit?

Answer (score 1):

Each joint in the rig has animation information
Originally I was only getting the information the first joint that had animations on it and not its children that also had animations attached

i.e. lets say your rig hierarchy is
hips > rightShoulder > arm > elbow > wrist

and your animations were on the shoulder, arm, elbow, and wrist joints

you **do not** have any animations on your hip joint

using `enumerateChildNodes` will only grab the information from the shoulder joint

using `enumerateHierarchy` will grab all the animation information from the shoulder, the elbow, AND the wrist joint

see below for my function that I used:
**note that I had separately loaded and saved my 3D model onto an SCNNode and that was passed in so I could attach the animations to it**

```
func loadAttachAnim_DAE(fileName: String, modelNode: SCNNode){
        let scene = SCNScene(named: fileName)!

        //find top level animation
        var animationPlayer: SCNAnimationPlayer! = nil


        scene.rootNode.enumerateHierarchy{ (child, stop)  in
            if !child.animationKeys.isEmpty {
                print ("child = \(child) -----------------")
                animationPlayer = child.animationPlayer(forKey: child.animationKeys[0])

                modelNode.addAnimationPlayer(animationPlayer, forKey: "\(child)")
                animationPlayer.play()

            }
        }
    }
```